# Why is one function being called and another repeating?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to do a small group project of a washing company's software. The login_Driver() function has an if statement in the end which calls another function if true but its not calling the function.

```
def login_Driver():
    print("Welcome to Sky Laundry")
    print("Login Driver Menu")
    print("Enter Username")
    driver_username = str(input())
    print("Enter Password")
    driver_password = str(input())
    '''text_file = open("driver_username.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(driver_username)
    text_file.close()'''

    text_file = open("driver_username.txt", "r")
    driver_username_check = text_file.readline()
    text_file.close()

    text_file = open("driver_password.txt", "r")
    driver_password_check = text_file.readline()
    text_file.close()

    if driver_username_check == driver_username and driver_password_check == driver_password:
        print("Login successful")
        return driver_username
        driver_Account()
    else:
        print("Login failed")




def login_Customer():
    print("Welcome to Sky Laundry")
    print("Login Customer")
    print("Enter Username")
    customer_username = str(input())
    print("Enter Password")
    customer_password = str(input())
    '''text_file = open("customer_username.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(customer_username)
    text_file.close()'''

    text_file = open("customer_username.txt", "r")
    customer_username_check = text_file.readline()
    text_file.close()

    text_file = open("customer_password.txt", "r")
    customer_password_check = text_file.readline()
    text_file.close()

    if customer_username_check == customer_username and customer_password_check == customer_password:
        print("Login successful")
        customer_Account()
        return customer_username
    else:
        print("Login failed")



def create_Account():
    print("Welcome to Sky Laundry")
    print("Enter whom you want to register as?")
    print("1.) Driver")
    print("2.) Customer")
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        print("Driver Registration Menu")
        print("Enter your Username")
        new_driver_username = str(input())
        print("Enter you Password")
        new_driver_password = str(input())

        text_file = open("driver_username.txt", "w")
        text_file.write(new_driver_username)
        text_file.close()

        text_file = open("driver_password.txt", "w")
        text_file.write(new_driver_password)
        text_file.close()

        print("Registration Successful, taking you back to the Main Menu")
        main_Selection()
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Customer Registration Menu")
        print("Enter your Username")
        new_customer_username = str(input())
        print("Enter you Password")
        new_customer_password = str(input())

        text_file = open("customer_username.txt", "w")
        text_file.write(new_customer_username)
        text_file.close()

        text_file = open("customer_password.txt", "w")
        text_file.write(new_customer_password)
        text_file.close()

        print("Registration Successful, taking you back to the Main Menu")
        main_Selection()
    else:
        print("INVALID OPTION")


def driver_Account():
    print("Drivers Account")

def customer_Account():
    print(customer_account_name = login_Customer())
    print("Account")




print("Welcome to Sky Laundry")
print("1.) Login Driver")
print("2.) Login Customer")
print("3.) Create Account")
print("4.) User Exit")


def main_Selection():
    print("Welcome to Sky Laundry")
    print("1.) Login Driver")
    print("2.) Login Customer")
    print("3.) Create Account")
    print("4.) User Exit")

    if opt is 1:
        login_Driver()
    elif opt is 2:
        login_Customer()
    elif opt is 3:
        create_Account()
    elif opt is 4:
        login_Driver()
    else:
        print("INVALID OPTION PLEASE TRY AGAIN")
        main_Selection()

opt = int(input())
main_Selection()
```

Here's the output

```
>>> 
Welcome to Sky Laundry
1.) Login Driver
2.) Login Customer
3.) Create Account
4.) User Exit
1
Welcome to Sky Laundry
1.) Login Driver
2.) Login Customer
3.) Create Account
4.) User Exit
Welcome to Sky Laundry
Login Driver Menu
Enter Username
levsingh
Enter Password
12345
Login successful
>>>
```

Comment: What is the output you're getting? It's always helpful to post that.

Comment: yes i have edited the post and added the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
    return driver_username
    driver_Account()
```

A return statement will always end the function you're in and execute no more lines, so you'll never get further than that. You would need to flip the order of these two lines to get driver_Account to be called.

Also in your main_Selection you don't ask for input, so the user can never provide a new number. An invalid input will cause infinite recursion and crash the program. You also left the body of the function outside of itself. So all the print lines will print out before you even call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a -

```
return driver_username
```

Immediately before the call to `driver_Account()`.

Rather than sprinkling code inbetween function definitions, you should use a main function -

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Welcome to Sky Laundry")
    print("1.) Login Driver")
    print("2.) Login Customer")
    print("3.) Create Account") 
    print("4.) User Exit")
    opt = int(input())
    main_Selection()
```